# Jquery plugin, паттерны плагинов и разбитие плагина на несколько файлов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть самописный плагин на jquery, реализованный по варианту самонастраиваемого плагина (см https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/39442/ заголовок "Самонастраиваемый плагин").

Из-за того, что плагин стал очень большим, его нужно разнести не несколько файлов. 
Но чтобы был доступ к основным опциям и основному объекту плагина. Как это можно провернуть?

Пытался во втором файле использовать нечто похожее, но ничего не выходит:

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
 $.fn.plugin.prototype.moduleN = function(){
     console.log('это вот расширение для плагина');
 }
})(jQuery);
```

Но при вызове этого метода нет. Я понимаю почему так происходит, но не понимаю как переделать чтобы была возможность в других файлах добавлять дополнительные методы в основной плагин.

Может есть какой-то иной паттерн?

---

Могу ещё упростить вопрос:

1 .js файл:

```
   $.fn.pluginName = function(options){
      return {
        method1 : function(methodOptions){},
        method2 : function(methodOptions){},
      }
  }
```

2 .js файл:

как добавить в $.fn.pluginName ещё один метод method3?

Чтобы потом в 3-м .js файле это вызывалось примерно так:

`$('...').pluginName(options).method3(methodOptions);`

Ну и само собой через this (или другим способом) в method3 нужен доступ к основным опциям плагина и общим параметрам/переменным.

Comment: во второй части вопроса - никак, так как при каждом вызове `.pluginName` будет создаваться новый объект

Comment: @Grundy а какой тогда другой способ есть разбить плагин на несколько файлов? Или без вариантов только в 1 файле всё держать? На продакшене пофиг, всё минифицируется, а вот работать, когда тысячи строк в одном файле, неудобно.

Comment: надо по другому плагин делать просто, по ссылке есть пример с конструктором. плюс добавить метод который добавит в прототип метод